# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid uri '/Assignment/rest/words/{name}/protection': escaped absolute path not valid

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest

i have spring restful web service, which is working fine with the postman(plugin in chrome) with URL (http://localhost:8080/Assignment/rest/words/{name}/protection) which requires 1 parameter named as "name"

and i have httpclient written in java too. with the following code.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

PostMethod method = new PostMethod("http://localhost:8080/Assignment/rest/words/{name}/protection");
method.setParameter("name", "value");

    byte[] responseBody = null;
    int statusCode = 0;
    try {
        // Executing method.
        statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);
        }catch(Exception e){}
        // checking status code
        if (statusCode != HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
            System.err.println("Method failed: " + method.getStatusLine());
        }

        // Reading response body.
        responseBody = method.getResponseBody();
```

on  `statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);` its shows error as follows

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid uri 'http://localhost:8080/Assignment/rest/words/{name}/protection': escaped absolute path not valid    org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.<init>(HttpMethodBase.java:222)    org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.ExpectContinueMethod.<init>(ExpectContinueMethod.java:93)     org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.EntityEnclosingMethod.<init>(EntityEnclosingMethod.java:119)  org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod.<init>(PostMethod.java:106)    com.aspose.talib.service.WordService.getDataFromURL(WordService.java:50)    com.aspose.talib.service.WordService.postRequestForProtectData(WordService.java:37)     com.aspose.talib.web.WordController.init(WordController.java:21)    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)     sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)    javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:183)     javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:161)   org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:173)   org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)    com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)  javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)  javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)  javax.faces.component.UIOutput.getValue(UIOutput.java:174)  com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:205)     com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.getCurrentValue(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:355)    com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicRenderer.encodeEnd(HtmlBasicRenderer.java:164)  javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:920)   javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)  javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)  javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1859)  com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:458)     com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:134)   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)    javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:659)  org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Please help

Comment: Looks like `PostMethod.setParameter()` and `PostMethod.toString()` don't work as you expected. I.e. the parameter isn't set. Can you tell me the fully qualified name of this class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, characters like curly braces are not allowed in the `URI`.  You have to encode that part.

Try something like this:

```
PostMethod method = new PostMethod(URIUtil.encodePath("http://localhost:8080/Assignment/rest/words/{name}/protection", "UTF-8"));
method.setParameter("name", "value");
```

`URIUtil` is from `commons-httpclient-3.1`.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: i was using URIBuilder for encoding and it gives 400 bad request , you great

Answer (score 0):

Its better you use URLBuilder first then assign built URL to contructor argument:

URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder();

Comment: it shows java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 44: http://localhost:8080/Assignment/rest/words/{name}/protection